# How to deal with `.partial` WAL segments generated by Postgres `pg_receivewal` command?

Tags: postgresql, backup, write-ahead-logging

`pg_receivewal` creates a `.partial` file for incomplete WAL segment. My question is how to deal with this file during recovery. If I just leave it as it is, last transactions don't recover. If I rename the file removing `.partial` post-fix, the recovery procedure crashes with the error:

```
FATAL:  archive file "000000010000000C00000080" has wrong size: 152 instead of 16777216
```

The only way I found is to remove this `.partial` segment after the previous recovery crash and start the procedure again. This way db seems fully recovered.

What the proper way to deal with these `.partial` segments?

My db version is 11.5.

**Update:**

Following Laurenz advice I ended up with running next command right before starting the recovery.

- it testes if there's no another version of the partial segment
- decompresses it (as I use `pg_receivewal` with `--compress` flag)
- augments it with nulls
- and copies the fixed segment into `pg_wal` folder

```
find /backup/wal -name "*.partial" -exec sh -c ' \
    NAME=`basename "$0" .gz.partial`; \
    DEST=$PGDATA/pg_wal/$NAME; \
    test ! -f $DEST && \
    zcat $0 > $NAME && \
    truncate -s16M $NAME && \
    mv $NAME $DEST \
' '{}' \;
```

Notice it's relying on `$PGDATA` environment variable which usually isn't set.

Comment: Why is the file short?  What pg_receivewal usually does is create a zero-filled full-length file, then overwrite it incrementally with real data.  Why is that not working for you?

Comment: @jjanes hmm... it's probably because of compression

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hmm, good question.

I suggest that you rename it and fill it with zeros at the end, for example using

```
dd if=/dev/zero of=000000010000000C00000080 oflag=append conv=notrunc bs=1024 count=16416
```

This could be part of your `restore_command`.

Comment: so there's no an official way to do it? I'm really surprised as anyone testing their recovery procedure should encounter this problem. If I'd like to keep the backup intact, would be there any difference if I copy this last partial segment into `$PGDATA/pg_wal` and fill it with zeros there?

Comment: I haven't found anything better. You can also copy it to `pg_wal`, but I think `restore_command` with a shell script is the natural way.